# Сравнение даты из списка, попадает ил она в диапазон дат

Tags: python, datetime

Получаю из базы данных список дат.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(config.base_sql)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT date FROM smena')
info_sql = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

И вот сейчас я пытаюсь понять, как мне сделать следующую конструкцию. У меня есть дата 1 и дата 2, я хочу узнать, попадает ли каждая дата из списка в промежуток между дата 1 и дата 2.

UPD:

из базы я получают список дат, мне необходимо вывести те даты, которые попадают в заданный промежуток.

Пример я получаю список дат:

```
[('13-12-2017',), ('13-12-2018',), ('13-12-2015',), ('21-12-2027',), ('21-07-2022',), ('21-07-2028',)]
```

Мне нудно понять, какие даты попадают в промежуток с 01.06.2022 по 01.08.2022. Промежуток будет формироваться позже автоматов за текущий месяц.
Возможно есть ли какая-то библиотека, или я не вижу простого решения.

UPD2:

Видимо без парсера дат мне не обойтись.

UPD3:

Из базы я получаю следующие значения и типы:

info_sql = list [((str),tuple),((str),tuple),((str),tuple)]

т.е. внути типо list, внути контежи с str.

Comment: А что сразу не выбрать нужные?

Comment: Этот модуль будет получать промежуток из другого модуля, проще вынести нужные даты в дельную функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать модуль `datetime`
Вот пример:

```py
import datetime
date1 = datetime.date(day=1, month=1, year=2023)
date2 = datetime.date(day=31, month=1, year=2023)
date3 = datetime.date(day=15, month=1, year=2023)
print(date1 < date3 < date2)
# Возвращает True
```

Если вам понадобится перевести строку в объект типа `datetime.Date`, вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), вот пример:

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('24052010', "%d%m%Y").date())
# datetime.date(2010, 5, 24)
```

UPD:  Чтобы преобразовать список с кортежами строк, в список с датами, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```py
import datetime


def convert_to_date_list(str_list: list[tuple[str]]) -> list[datetime.datetime]:
    return [datetime.datetime.strptime(tup[0], "%d-%m-%Y") for tup in str_list]


def in_range(date_list: list[datetime.datetime], date_from: datetime.datetime, date_to: datetime.date) -> list[datetime.datetime]:
    return [date for date in date_list if date_from <= date <= date_to]


date_from = datetime.datetime(day=1, month=6, year=2022)
date_to = datetime.datetime(day=1, month=8, year=2022)
str_list = [('13-12-2017',), ('13-12-2018',), ('13-12-2015',),
            ('21-12-2027',), ('21-07-2022',), ('21-07-2028',)]
date_list = convert_to_date_list(str_list)
filtered = in_range(date_list, date_from, date_to)
for date in filtered:
    print(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный, пожалуйста!)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне необходимо понять, какие даты попадают в заданный промежуток и вывести эти даты.

Comment: @VladimirYusupov вы можете с помощью цикла `for` проверить каждую дату

Comment: Не могу придумать, какая должна быть конструкция и я так понял, что мне нужно переформатировать каждый элемента к формату datetime + переменные date 1 и date 2 тоже в этом формате делать?

Comment: Ну естественно всё нужно приводить к одному формату. Вообще говоря, можно было бы просто "перевернуть" даты в виде строки, приведя к формату `yyyy-mm-dd` и тогда их можно сравнивать просто как строки между собой.

Comment: @CrazyElf я их в sql в таком формате заливаю. По идее же я могу к любому формате привести, сразу вводя в sql. Тогда я бы мог просто сделать c помощью функции while? и как я буду их сравнивать списком? тогда же мне нужно вывести все элементы списка отдельно.

Comment: @VladimirYusupov Алгоритм, который я предлагаю: 1. Считать даты из базы данных, они будут являться строками; 2. Перевести строки в тип данных `Date` с помощью функции `strptime` (описал в ответе), пусть они будут храниться в списке `dates`; 3. date1, date2 также задать как объект типа `Date`, пример есть в ответе; 4. Пройтись с помощью `for date in dates` и сравнить `if date1 <= date <= date2:`

Comment: @diduk001 сейчас проверил по типу данных, из базы я получаю  list, внути контежи с str. В формат не получается легко перевести.

Comment: @VladimirYusupov обновил ответ

Comment: @diduk001 Спасибо, сработало.